# How do you burn an ISO image on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, iso-image, burning, compact-disc

Is there a utility built into the Mac software to allow for burning ISO downloaded from the internet.

Or.. Is there a better utility on the Net for performing this function?

Comment: For what it's worth, I found out the hard way that right-clicking the `.iso` file and selecting `Burn "foo.iso" to Disc...` does **NOT** do this ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The steps below show how to use the Disk Utility functionality. (Copied from [Life Hacker](http://lifehacker.com/software/mac-os-x/mac-tip--how-to-burn-an-iso-or-dmg-file-to-disc-251758.php)).

1. Launch Disk Utility (Applications > Utilities).
2. Insert your blank DVD or CD.
3. Drag and drop your .dmg or .iso file to the left pane in Disk Utility. Now both the blank disk and the .iso/.dmg should be listed.
4. Select the .iso/.dmg file you want to burn to disc, and click on the Burn button. A dialog box confirming the destination (your blank CD/DVD) will appear, as shown:
5. Sit back and wait while your new disc gets written!

Alternatively you could use a third party application like [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html)

Comment: I find Burn much easier to use.

Comment: I <3        Burn

Comment: I would also recommend Burn as a reliable CD\DVD burning application.

Answer (score 10):

It's very, very easy to do on the command line (open `Terminal`):

```
hdiutil burn /path/to/iso
```

If it's a CD/RW and you want to erase it first:

```
hdiutil burn -erase /path/to/iso
```

It's funny, but this is pretty much the best CLI for CD burning on any OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Disk Utility" program that comes with the OS.

- insert blank disc
- start the "Disk utility" program
- select File -> Open Disc Image -> select your ISO image to be burned
- Choose your .iso file from the volume list
- Burn it!!!